# Simple Question -- What does the NoSuchElementException and WebDriverException mean in this function?

Tags: python, function, selenium, methods, beautifulsoup

I am trying to incorporate a web scraper in my current workflow. I am very new to Python and web-scraping, and am working through an example problem before I develop my current solution.

Here is what I think the code below means.

We're defining a function that draws class names from the current page. I have never seen the "try" and "except" blocks before, but they seem intuitive: the code attempts to find elements based on the class name and then put them in a list.

```py
### Next we define a function that pulls class names from the current page. 

def get_list_by_class_name(class_name = "main_image "):
    ###Get list of text in all element by class_name
    try: 
        all_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(class_name)
        element_list = [x.text for x in all_elements if len(x.text) > 0]
    except (NoSuchElementException, WebDriverException) as e: 
        print(e)
    return element_list
```

I am confused by what the "except" block implies. What exactly are the NoSuchElementException and WebDriverExceptions in selenium? And why are we printing them? Just for error handling down the road?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoSuchElementException` will be thrown if there are no elements matching `class_name`.

`WebDriverException` stands for basically "any Selenium exception". It could happen, for example, if an element was deleted after it was matched by class by before its text was retreived.

Printing doesn't carry any particular logic and most likely left here for debugging. It will print the exception type and the information it carries, e.g. the element related to the exception. In fact, the program will fail right after this line because `element_list` is not defined.